# How can I remove Settings.bundle from previous app version?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

My iPad app currently uses Settings.bundle to allow settings both via the built-in Settings.app as well as via InAppSettingsKit. I now want to switch to IASK entirely and disable the built-in settings. I have renamed the Settings.bundle folder to InAppSettings.bundle, but when I deploy this new version to my test device, the old Settings data seems to stick around - at least, I can still access the old settings via Settings.app.

Is there a way to force removal of Settings.bundle when a new version of the app is installed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you do a clean build in Xcode. For development builds, you also need to remove the app from the Simulator or device first. Otherwise old files are left in place.

Comment: This also happens with clean builds. Removing the app isn't really a viable option for users who update via the app store.

Comment: Deleting the app is only needed in development. Real users doing an update won't need to delete the app.